# Error Retrieving Data From DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am requesting this data from a database and it works fine,

```
<?php
                                    $stmt = $con->query('SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC');
                               while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                $title    = htmlspecialchars($row['title']);
                                $content  = htmlspecialchars($row['content']);
                                $category = htmlspecialchars($row['category']);

                     ?>
                    <div class="features">
                        <div class="box"><img src="Developer/common-files/icons/time@2x.png" width="100" height="100" alt="Wuno Inc.">       
                             <h6><?php echo htmlspecialchars($category); ?> - <?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?></h6>
                             <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($content); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <?php
                      }
                      ?>
```

Then when I do the same thing with a different table like this,

```
 $stmt = $con->query('SELECT * FROM taggePlaces ORDER BY created_time DESC');
                                       while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                            $id   = htmlspecialchars($row['id']);
                                            $created_time = htmlspecialchars($row['created_time']);
                                            $place_id = htmlspecialchars($row['place_id']);
                                            $city = htmlspecialchars($row['city']);
                                            $country = htmlspecialchars($row['country']);
                                            $latitude = htmlspecialchars($row['latitude']);
                                            $longitude = htmlspecialchars($row['longitude']);
                                            $state = htmlspecialchars($row['state']);
                                            $street = htmlspecialchars($row['street']);
                                            $zip = htmlspecialchars($row['zip']);
                                            $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
```

I get this error and I can not figure out why...

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in
```

The error is on the line with the `while loop`

I found this thread that evidently explains the same issue but I don't understand why or the solution.

[Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455623/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-on-a-non-object)

`Note` This `ORDER BY created_time DESC` is a timestamp

Comment: *"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in"* - Keep going; in "what/where"? Add `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Is your sql query succeed?

Comment: I mention in my question the error is in the line with the loop.

Comment: @NichoDiaz So if your query failed `$smtp` is false.